# Compare two pandas series with a condition and assign False if a condition is matched else keep the value of first series

Tags: pandas, series

I have two pandas series,

```
s1 = pd.Series([False, True, False, True, False], index= np.arange(0,5))

0    False

1     True

2    False

3     True

4    False

dtype: bool

s2 = pd.Series([False, False, False, True, True], index= np.arange(0,5))

0    False

1    False

2    False

3     True

4     True

dtype: bool
```

Expected result,

```
0    False

1     True

2    False

3    False

4    False
```

How to compare these two pandas series?
I want to compare the s1 series with s2 and keep the value of the s1 series if there is no match.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `&` for bitwise `AND` with inverting mask by `~`:

```
print (s1 & ~s2)
0    False
1     True
2    False
3    False
4    False
dtype: bool
```

Comment: Jezrael, can you explain the logic to me once?

Comment: @Rohit - Inverting mask means change True to False and Fale to True, so Series `pd.Series([False, False, False, True, True], index= np.arange(0,5))` is changed to `pd.Series([True, True, True, False, False], index= np.arange(0,5))`. `AND` means output is `True`, if both `s1` and `s2` are Trues, so here only values for index `1`

Comment: Jezrael, thank you for the explanation.